# Avoid high overdraw and long View drawing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout, layout-inflater

I have a problem with a BI application I'm writing.

The application uses AChartEngine for charts and most of the table data is inflated programmatically. There are currently two main problems I'm facing:

1. When the application switches orientation, it takes around 8-10 seconds to redraw every dashboard element (i.e. to display data). Is this a problem with overdraw or something else (this happens on N4, N5, Note 3...). This is unacceptable and I really need to fix this!
2. There's almost 4x overdraw on table row elements, and I managed to get it lower - to around 2-2.5x with `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null)`. How do I fix this much overdraw as everything is inflated from code? (here's an example of how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/2lio5q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the orientation working very slowly. I applied few flags to my FragmentActivity in the manifset and it works much better now, flags are `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"`.

Keep in mind that for this kind of thing it is much better and Android-like to use the FragmentPagerAdapter than FragmentActivity, but I work with what I got.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding overdraw:
Have you checked Romain Guy's Android Performance Case Study:
http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html

You can also find several Google I_O Videos by him (some of them dated) that might be helpful.

Comment: I actually did and that's how I tried optimizing my overdraw a bit (and partly succeeded), but I still don't understand if that's why it takes so long to switch orientation or not.

Comment: Have you tried traceview to find out why drawing takes so long?

Comment: I did, but I don't think I'm 100% on the results, here's the chart (that huge spike is when I changed the orientation).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkeIoakarA56dHdDdzI3MFhKc0RIOW04ZmVNWUFwbHc&output=html

Comment: Also, here's the trace for the app, I think you guys will see where's the issue (when I rotated the phone). It's process 26246: https://db.tt/7blFrjS3